# d3d9 how to register software device

Tags: direct3d9

on win7 no graphics card

IDirect3D9::createDevice() with BehaviorFlags=D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING，DeviceType=D3DDEVTYPE_SW,return D3DERR_INVALIDCALL.

D3DDEVTYPE_SW need IDirect3D9::RegisterSoftwareDevice to register pluggable software device first in microsoft document.
is there software device work?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: founction `D3D9GetSWInfo` in `rgb9rast.dll` should be work at IDirect3D9::RegisterSoftwareDevice.```rastlib = LoadLibrary(L"rgb9rast.dll");d3d->RegisterSoftwareDevice(GetProcAddress(rastlib, "D3D9GetSWInfo"));
 ```

Answer (score 1):

There's never been a `D3DDEVTYPE_SW` for Direct3D 9 to my knowledge. There was one for Direct3D 8 a long, long time ago.

For modern DirectX software rendering, you'd use [WARP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3darticles/directx-warp) with DirectX 11 or DirectX 12.